# How can I use rounded borders with CSS?

Tags: css, border

Is there a way in the newer CSS standards to provide round borders?
It is not possible in CSS level 2.

Comment: Thanks guys, shows were I've been. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in CSS 3.

`border-radius: 4em;`

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  CSS3 already has it.

Many browsers already have it.

- In Mozilla/gecko browsers you need `-moz-border-radius` though they are transitioning to `border-radius`.
- In Safari/Chrome/webkit browsers you need `-webkit-border-radius`.
- IE9 and above need `border-radius` (IE8 and below don't support it at all).
- In the future when CSS3 is widely adopted you'll just need `border-radius` in all browsers.

At the moment it's a good idea to use all three, plus `-o-border-radius` if you're worried about Opera.

Answer (score 2):

[Border-radius: create rounded corners with CSS!](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)

This box should have a rounded corners for Firefox, Safari/Chrome, Opera and IE9.
The code for this example is, in theory, quite simple:

```
#example1 {
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

However, for the moment, you’ll also need to use the -moz- prefix to support Firefox (see the browser support section of this article for further details):

```
#example1 {
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What [Thomas Rutter said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473979/will-css-ever-have-border1px-solid-black-round/3474002#3474002), plus here is a [handy resource](http://borderradius.com/) because WebKit and Gecko use different properties for things such as `top-left`.